# Count files in a directory tree

Tags: shell-script, files, find

For the consistency check of a backup program, I want to define a function which counts all files in a directory including all files in subdirs, subsubdirs and so on.

The solution I am trying so far is as follows:

```
countfiles() {
  local cdir=$1
  local files=$(ls -la $cdir | grep -cv '^[dl]')

  local dirstring=$(ls -la $cdir | grep '^d' | egrep -o ' \.?[^[:space:].][^[:space:]]+$')
  local directories=(${dirstring//"\n"/})

  echo ${directories[@]}


  for dir in ${directories[@]}; do
    echo -n "$dir "
    echo -n 'filecount >> '
    local dirfiles=$(countfiles "$cdir/$dir")
    echo -n $dirfiles
    echo ' <<'
    #files=$(($files+$dirfiles))
  done

  echo $files

}
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
.config .i3 .scripts
.config filecount >> gtk-3.0 termite gtk-3.0 filecount >> 2 << termite filecount >> 2 << 1 <<
.i3 filecount >> 5 <<
.scripts filecount >> 2 <<
5
```

While the actualization of my `$files` counter is commented atm and I may need to unlocalize it, right now I set all variables as local to avoid any interference.

The directory tree is as follows:

```
/.scripts/backup_dotfiles.sh
/.config/termite/config
/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
/.i3/config
/.i3/i3blocks.conf
/.i3/lockicon.png
/.i3/lockscreen.sh
/.gtkrc-2.0
/.bashrc
/.zshrc
/.i3
/.Xresources
```

My questions:

- Why does it always count the files +1 except for the master directory?
- Why does it count anything in the '.config' directory, as there are no files in there?
- How can I fix this?

Comment: Oops. I actually looked into this question, but I did not fing the recursion which also handles the files in the subdirectories. But yes, it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to just use `find`. Assuming you don't have files with newlines in their names, just something like this would do:

```
find "$dir" -type f | wc -l
```

`-type f` matches regular files, but not directories, pipes, sockets or whatever.

The usual output of `find` separates the filenames with newlines, so if any of the names contain newlines, the output will be ambiguous. With GNU find, something like this would work:

```
find "$dir" -type f -printf . | wc -c
```

That has `find` print only a dot for each file, and counts the dots.

Other versions of `find` don't have `-printf` but we can use the trick of passing the input path with doubled slashes. They are treated like a single slash, but will not naturally appear otherwise in the output since file names cannot contain slashes. Then count the double-slashes in the output:

```
find "$dir//" -type -f | grep -c //
```

---

If we want to do that with purely a shell script, we can have the shell
list the filenames, [no need to use `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), e.g. in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=0
shopt -s dotglob
countfiles() {
        local f;
        for f in * ; do 
                if [ -f "$f" ] ; then          # count regular files
                        files=$((files + 1))
                elif [ -d "$f" ] ; then        # recurse into directories
                        cd "$f"
                        countfiles
                        cd ..
                fi
        done
}
cd "$1"
countfiles
echo $files
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of files in a directory and sub directories by using:

```
 find path_to_directory -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: Assuming you don't have files with newlines in their names.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it always count the files +1 except for the master directory?

Cause ls -la also adds the string `total 20` to the output. I can see that for "master" directory it also shows +1 value.

> Why does it count anything in the '.config' directory, as there are no files in there?

The same reason. `total ..` string produced by `ls`.

> How can I fix this?

Do not use your script :)
I mean really, it's overcomplicated. We have nice `find` in here. All your script will turn into something like that (if you need files per directory):

```
find $yourdir -type d | while read dir ; do 
    echo "$dir == $(find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l) files" ; 
done
```

or just (if you need sum value):

```
find $yourdir -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: Assuming you don't have files with newlines in their names.